# How to validate yaml and yml files in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

In the project I have been working on we use yaml files to automatically create our responses and requests kotlin classes. for example:

```
title: Student
type: object
properties:
  id:
    type: number
  name:
    type: string
```

Since the classes are created automatically I cannot add any annotations because everytime I build my application the files will be created again and the old ones will be deleted.
How can I validate the properties (@NotBlank, @Min, @Max, @Positive, etc) in the yaml files?

The only one I have used is 'required' to set the required properties.

Comment: Which tool generates the classes? You seem to be using JSON schema which [does support ranges](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#id7) but it depends on the tool whether it will generate `@Min` / `@Max` from that.

Comment: It is a gradle plugin and I am using JSON schema, besides the supported validation [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/) I'd like to use some customized validations with business logic. Do you know any approach to it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of jackson-dataformat-yaml and javax.validation.constraints.

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Model code:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class TopLevel {

    @NotBlank
    String title;

    @NotBlank
    String type;

    @NotBlank
    Property properties;

}

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class Property {

    @NotBlank
    String id;  
    
}
```